# Passing JTextField to another class

Tags: java, swing, class, jtextfield

I am very new to Java and I am trying to pass a JTextField to another class.
Here is my code:

Method to send the JTextField from `SellWindow` class:

```
public JTextField sendTextField(){
    return addItemField;
}
```

Method to get the JTextField in `EnterAction` class:

```
public JTextField getItemField(){
    SellWindow field=new SellWindow();
    addItem=field.sendTextField();
    return addItem;
}
```

Executing the data in `EnterAction` class:

```
public void enterData(){
    System.out.println(this.getItemField().getText()); //output blank 
    System.out.println(this.addItem); //output "null"        
}
```

I don't know where is the actual problem. After executing the code, it gives the following output as stated in the code's comments. It will be very helpful if someone could fix this problem. I am very new to Java and it's my first programe.

Comment: In those lines:
SellWindow field=new SellWindow();
addItem=field.sendTextField();
you are creating new SellWindow object and you are trying to access its TextField, which after creation of the object will be probably empty (null).

Comment: I find it difficult to believe that the first line of `enterData()` will output a blank line with the second line outputting `null`. Can you construct a [self-contained example](http://sscce.org/#selfcon)?

Comment: *"I am very new to Java and it's my first programme."*  Start coding command line programs!  By the time you approach GUI programming, the answer to this should be obvious.  And it is spelled 'program' unless you are a 19th century British theater owner - who commonly spelled it that way (i.e. incorrectly).

Comment: @AndrewThompson Do you mean the answer should be pretty obvious in general for this type of problem (I can't argue with you there) or that the answer for this specific problem, with the code provided, is pretty obvious? If it's the latter, I just can't see it.

Comment: @Dukeling 'In general'..

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you're trying to do, but from what I can tell, you have a SellWindow frame and an EnterAction frame, and you want to pass user input between the two. One issue I see is that in the getItemField method, you are creating a new SellWindow instance but not displaying it or allowing the user to interact with it at all. Instead, I would make SellWindow as a JDialog and once the user closes the dialog, get the input. Try this:

```
public JTextField getItemField(){
    SellWindow field=new SellWindow(null, true);
    field.setVisible(true);
    addItem=field.sendTextField();
    return addItem;
}
```